Mesop python. Getting user error: path / not registered
Error Meesage
Getting this error with the mesop sample code. Why?
import mesop as me
import mesop.labs as mel


@me.page(
    security_policy=me.SecurityPolicy(
    allowed_iframe_parents=["https://google.github.io"]
    ),
    path="/text_to_text",
    title="Text to Text Example",
)
def app():
    mel.text_to_text(
    upper_case_stream,
    title="Text to Text Example",
    transform_mode="replace"
  )

def upper_case_stream(s: str):
    return "Echo: " + s

I am guessing the server runs on http://localhost:32123 where it should be
http://localhost:32123/text_to_text.
I believe this part:
path="/text_to_text",
is to add /text_to_text to complete the link:http://localhost:32123. But the error happens.

how did you initialise your server? show that code

Did you ever get to the bottom of this? Setting the path to / makes it work fine but that's not what all the examples show?
I am using PyCharm and not CoLab

never mind, i have started using Reflex. Good documentation etc. Was previously know as pynecone i think

just use:
@me.page()
delete this code:
security_policy=me.SecurityPolicy(
allowed_iframe_parents=["https://google.github.io"]
),
path="/text_to_text",
title="Text to Text Example",

